# Is there a technique whereby Python can run 'mycode()' when a class in code that is not in my control is instantiated

Tags: python

So there is a class called `ClassInOtherCode` in module `othercode.py` that I **cannot alter**. In `othercode.py` there is a function called `otherfunc()` that sometimes instantiates `ClassInOtherCode`.

Before I run `otherfunc()` is there a way to tell Python to tell my code via some raised event or call some code of mine when `ClassInOtherCode` is instantiated?

I am not referring to my code checking if `ClassInOtherCode` is instantiated after the call to `otherfunc()`, but rather a push by Python to my code. By push, I am referring to a web pattern whereby the client browser receives info rather than continually asking for it.

My code is not a web app. I'm just trying to make an analogy so my question is hopefully clearer.

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly, but you could decorate otherfunc to callback your code whenever it is run. You can decorate it from your code when you import otherfunc parent module with a light monkey patching

Comment: Because you want to do something before ClassInOtherCode is instantiated? In that case I'd look in othercode.py and instantiated it myself before otherfunc() is called, or I'd place some calling code in my __init__..py for my module .  Could you provide a more concrete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [monkey-patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching) `ClassInOtherCode` if you don't have access to its source to add the required functionality to its `__init__` method:

```
from othermodule import otherfunc, ClassInOtherCode

default_init = ClassInOtherCode.__init__

def my_init(*args, **kwargs):
  print("ClassInOtherCode is instantiated!")
  default_init(*args, **kwargs)

ClassInOtherCode.__init__ = my_init

result = otherfunc()  # This should trigger your print statement
```

Comment: Thanks @Selcuk I'll have a play around with that. So to be clear. If something in otherfunc(), or any other code, instantiates ClassInOtherCode, then my_init() will be executed and any parameters supplied to ClassInOtherCode will still arrive to ClassInOtherCode via my_init() ?

Comment: @ThomasAJ That's correct. You are basically modifying its source code dynamically (i.e. for the current process only).